# Expressing the quadratic form of non symmetric matrix

Tags: quadratic-forms

$f(x) = \frac{1}2 x^T Gx + b^T x + c$

Suppose G is not a symmetric matrix. Show that the first term can
be rewritten to bring it into a symmetric form. Find the new expression in terms of G.

My approach :
Since G is not symmetric we can always write G as a sum of a symmetric (S) and anti-symmetric (A) matrix. Also $x^T A x =0$ .
Hence,$ x^T Gx = x^T ( S +A) x = x^T Sx +x^T Ax= x^T Sx $. But what exactly is meant by findng new expression in terms of G is not clear

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far could you get? Where are you stuck? This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question body. Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: @saulspatz changes done as per your suggestion. Thank you

Comment: $S=\frac12(G+G^T)$  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3369026/one-and-only-one-method-to-write-a-as-sum-of-symmetric-matrix-and-skew-symmetric

Answer (score 1):

When $G$ is not symmetric, the coefficient of $x_i x_j$ is $G_{ij} + G_{ji}$. So, you can just replace $G$ by a symmetric matrix $S$ that satisfies $S_{ij}+S_{ji} = G_{ij}+G_{ji}$, i.e. $S_{ij} = \frac  12 (S_{ij} + S_{ji})$. As mentioned in the comments, this means that $S = \frac 12 (G + G^T)$.